# Static linking of protocol buffers with codelite

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, static-linking, codelite

This is my first ever serious compiling experience on linux. I've installed codelite on ubuntu. I'm trying to build a shared library that uses protocol buffers. I've built protocol buffers with no problems. However, no matter what I do I cannot add protobuf statically to my shared library. I don't know what the problem is. I'm not getting any errors when compiling but the .so file is 80kb instead of >1.9MB. I know the file size because I'm using the same shared library on windows. What should I do?

Here's my compiler settings:

[image: Codelite compiler settings]

Here's my linker settings:

[image: Codelite linker settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've managed to do it. Here's what I did. First of all I compiled protocol buffers with the following flags

```
./configure "CFLAGS=-fPIC" "CXXFLAGS=-fPIC"
```

Then I switched to code blocks, it's ugly but get's the job done.